# Order function by increasing growth rate?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

**What is the order of the functions by increasing growth rate:**

1^(nlogn), n^logn, 2^5, sqrt(logn), 2^(n!), 1/n, n^2, 2^logn, n!, 100^n

**Here's my attempt:**

1^(nlogn)

2^5

1/n

sqrt(logn)

n^2

n^logn

2^logn

100^n

n!

2^(n!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to programming.

Comment: I am sure you could prove this directly by comparing how they all change for `n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Comment: 1/n has a negative growth rate.

Comment: http://graphsketch.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the easy part.

- `1 / n` is growing down - the bigger the n - the smaller the result
- `1^(n*log(n))` and `2^5` are both constants. So they both are `O(1)`.

Now we have one function that is clearly the smallest out of the rest:

- `sqrt(log(n))`

So we ended up with the following function which are unclear: `n^log(n), 2^(n!), n^2, n!, 100^n, 2^log(n)`. Some of them grow polynomially `2^log(n) = n ^ log(2)` is approximately `n ^ 0.7`. So we have another group:

- `2^log(n)`
- `n^2`

Out of the rest, the 'biggest' one is `2^(n!)`, then `n!` and then `100^n` and then`n ^ log(n)`

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you so much